# Get the total values in each month using Django QuerySet

Tags: django

I have this model for employee overtime hours

```
class Overtime(IncomeBase):
    day = models.DateField(verbose_name="Date")
    value = models.FloatField(default=1)
```

I need to extract the total value for each month. Now I am using a daily QuerySet in the manager.

```
class OvertimeManager(models.Manager):

    def daily_report(self):
        return self.values('day').annotate(hours=models.Sum('value')).order_by('-day')
```

However now I need a monthly report that will get the Sum of `value` for each month.
I tried to extract the month first but then I lose the values.

Note: the month should not have the total sum for all years, so specifically I need to group by `month,year`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Postgresql you can do this. Ofc there is similar fuctions.

```
Overtime.objects.extra({'month': "to_char(day, 'Mon')", "year": "extract(year from day)"}).values('month', 'year').annotate(Sum('value'))
```

More info: 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/functions-formatting.html
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html

Or django way:

```
from django.db import connection

truncate_month = connection.ops.date_trunc_sql('month','day')
Overtime.objects.extra({'month': truncate_month}).values('month').annotate(Sum('value'))
```

I think this will help you.

Comment: any other methods that doesn't require a specific database?